# Вставка изображения по ссылке в ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Парсится строка `JSON`, в которой много элементов. Текст каждого элемента успешно добавляется в `ListView`.

Так же там содержаться ссылки на картинки, для каждого элемента `ListView` своя картинка. Ссылка содержится в переменной    `small`.

Как реализовать данную подгрузку изображения и вставку в `ListView`?
Использую `SimpleAdapter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно написать свой собственный `CusromListAdapter`, который расширяется от `ArrayAdapter`.

[Статья по этой теме](https://habrahabr.ru/post/282594/)

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, советую использовать `RecycleView` - это более гибкое средство в отличии от `ListView`.
По поводу картинок, будь то `ListView` или `RecycleView`, нужно в адаптере при создании компонента, загрузить картинку в `ImageView` с помощью библиотеки, я вам советую `Picasso` - она очень быстро выполняет эту задачу, и при этом обладает автоматическим кэшированием.

```
    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    //......
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    //......

    Picasso.with("Your context").load("Your URL").into(holder.imageView);
    }
```

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null`

Ругается на строчку с Picasso

Comment: Проверьте, правильно ли вы инициализируете `ImageView`. И на этапе вызова метода Picasso инициализирован ли `ImageView`, или он `null`. Также контекст должен браться через метод `getContext()`, а не `this.context`.

Comment: `ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgSmall);

Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(small).into(img);`

Comment: Какой-то из параметров, который вы передает в метод - `null`, посмотрите через debug, который. Он и вызывает ошибку в методе.

Comment: img передаёт null, как это исправить?

Comment: Я советую изучить вам какой-то пример по созданию `ListView` и загрузки туда информации. Как я могу понимать, `ImageView` - `null`, потому что он не относится к ParentView.

Comment: Текстовая информация в ListVIew добавляется нормально

Comment: В ImgView устанавливается картинка допустим из ресурсов?

Comment: Да, из ресурсов получилось поставить картинку.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38819/discussion-between-sergon146-and-vyacheslav-martynenko).

Comment: В чате ответил.

Answer (score 1):

Подключаете к проекту какую-нибудь библиотеку для загрузки картинок, например [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco). Для своего SimpleAdapter устанавливаете свой вью биндер методом [setViewBinder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#setViewBinder(android.widget.SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder)) в котором для вьюхи с картинкой с помощью вышеозначенной либы запускаете загрузку и отображение картинки.

Ссылку так же как и текст закидываете в адаптер, так сказать "напротив" идишника вьюхи с картинкой, соответственно в биндере проверяете что пришла вьюха с ид ImageView (или виджета из библиотеки если там свой ImageView) и если это так, то запускаете загрузку картинки, если нет то возвращайте false что бы адаптер заполнял остальные вьюхи данными как и раньше.

Comment: А можно по-подробнее?
У меня в цикле парсится JSON, на каждой итерации я получаю текст и ссылку. Текст я закидываю в адаптер. Что делать с ссылкой?

Comment: Добавил в ответ подробностей.